# Display key and array values using *ngFor in angular 9

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ngfor, angular9

**JSON**

```
{
 "cars":
{
  "12345": [1960, 1961, 1962],
  "4567": [2001, 2002]
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<strong>Plate and year</strong>
<div *ngFor="let list of lists">
{{list.cars}}
</div>
```

**I need to display like this:**

*Plate and year*

*12345- 1960, 1961, 1962.*

*4567- 2001, 2002.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your data structure, you can achieve this using the [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) and additional nested `*ngFor`. `KeyValuePipe` allows you to iterate over an object similar to `Object.entries` providing a `key` and `value` property for each item. In this case the `value` will be an array that you can iterate over using an `*ngFor`:

```
<strong>Plate and year</strong>
<div *ngFor="let list of lists">
  <div *ngFor="let car of list.cars | keyvalue">
    <div>{{car.key}} - <div *ngFor="let year of car.value">{{year}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aynqwu?file=src/app/app.component.html) in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Very clean and great way of using keyvalue pipe. Thanks a lot @AlexanderStaroselsky xoxo